# Laravel 5.4 redirect to named route inside named group

Tags: php, laravel

Given next routes group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts', 'as' => 'posts'], function() {
  Route::get('/', 'PostsController@list')->name('list');
  Route::get('/{post}', 'PostsController@item')->name('item');
});
```

I am trying to redirect to posts/list route.

Tried using dot:

```
return redirect()->route('posts.list');
```

Slash:

```
return redirect()->route('posts/list');
```

Only route's name:

```
return redirect()->route('list');
```

Nothing works and I can't find a reference in docs.

Comment: Does `return redirect("posts/list");` work?

Comment: perhaps you may need to dump the routes cache to generate them again if you just recently added the name portion. I don't see anything wrong using the route name redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named group is not supposed to add anything after it's name so your routes names should be `postslist` and `postsitem`.